# AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver instead of Service - is that bad ? (Timeout)

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

**BACKGROUND INFO:**

I need to update some data from the web, about every hour or so, even when my app is closed. The update of the data itself takes about 40 seconds to 1 minute. It is then saved as a Serializable to a file. This file is read when my app starts.

**THIS IS THE APPROACH I TOOK FOR THE MOMENT (not using a Service)**

use the AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver like this :

```
private void set_REFRESH_DATA_Alarm(){
    mContext = Main.this;
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    broadcast_intent = new Intent(mContext, 
            RepeatingAlarmReceiver_REFRESH_DATA.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, 0,  broadcast_intent, 0);
    // do a REFRESH every hour, starting for the first time in 30 minutes from now ...
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    long triggerAtTime = now.getTimeInMillis()+ (1 * 30 * 60 * 1000); // starts in 30 minutes
    long repeat_alarm_every = (1 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // repeat every 60 minutes
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtTime, 
            repeat_alarm_every, pendingIntent);
}
```

My **RepeatingAlarmReceiver_REFRESH_DATA.class** takes care of updating the Data from the Web:

```
public class RepeatingAlarmReceiver_REFRESH_DATA extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static Context mContext;
    ConnectivityManager mConnectivity;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mContext = context;
        // if Network connection is OK (Wifi or Mobile) then Load data ...
        mConnectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        Log.i("Hub",
                "mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(0)="
                        + mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(0));
        Log.i("Hub",
                "mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(1)="
                        + mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(1));
        if ((mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                || (mConnectivity.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
            Log.i("Hub", "Connectivity OK ...");
            Refresh_HIST_DATA();
        } else {
            // else Show Dialog "No network connection" ...
            Log.i("Hub",
                    "No network connection for the moment... will try again later!");
        }
    }

    // =========================================================================
    private void Refresh_HIST_DATA() {
        Log.i("Hub", "Refresh_HIST_DATA()... Starting ...");
        // etc...
    }
}
```

In the Manifest I have :

```
<receiver android:name="com.cousinHub.myapp.RepeatingAlarmReceiver_REFRESH_DATA" android:process=":remote" />
```

**PROBLEM :**

The alarm gets fired on time and the update starts but then after about 10 seconds it stops (Timeout):

> 06-25 11:55:05.278:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(76): Timeout of
>   broadcast BroadcastRecord{44bb4348
>   null} -
>   receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@44bcc670
>
> 06-25 11:55:05.278:
>   WARN/ActivityManager(76): Receiver
>   during timeout: ResolveInfo{44bb42c0
>   com.cousinHub.myapp.RepeatingAlarmReceiver_REFRESH_DATA
>   p=0 o=0 m=0x0}
>
> 06-25 11:55:05.278: INFO/Process(76):
>   Sending signal. PID: 819 SIG: 9
>
> 06-25 11:55:05.298:
>   INFO/ActivityManager(76): Process
>   com.cousinHub.myapp:remote (pid 819)
>   has died.

*ps: strangely enough, this "Timeout" does not happen after about 10 seconds on my HTC Hero (still on Android 1.5 - API Level 4) but well on my Nexus One (2.1-update1)*

**Questions :**

1. Why this timeout ? Any easy way to avoid this ?
2. Did I set up my BroadcastReceiver correctly in the manifest ? Do I need to add something (to avoid this timeout) ?
3. Should I absolutely go for a Service for this kind of "Refresh from Web" functionality ? (considering this article : http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/) 
   If YES (I should switch to a service): Any good snippets of code/tutorial for this ...

As allways, thanks for your help.

H.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Why this timeout ?

You are running on the main application thread. You cannot run on the main application thread for more than a few seconds. Also, while doing this, you are harming the performance of the device (because you are [running with foreground priority](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/16/code-pollution-background-foreground/)), such as causing frame-rate loss in games or videos.

> Any easy way to avoid this ?

Don't do significant work (>100ms) on the main application thread. Have your `BroadcastReceiver` delegate to an `IntentService`, perhaps a [`WakefulIntentService`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful).

> Did I set up my BroadcastReceiver
>   correctly in the manifest ?

Please please please please please get rid of the `android:process=:remote`. You do not need it, it is not helping you, and it is degrading performance of the device even further.

> Should I absolutely go for a Service
>   for this kind of "Refresh from Web"
>   functionality ? (considering this
>   article :
>   http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/)
>   If YES (I should switch to a service):
>   Any good snippets of code/tutorial for
>   this ...

IMHO, yes. Then again, I wrote that blog post. For an example, see the [`WakefulIntentService`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful) project.

Comment: and the WakefulIntentService will be able to "live" more than 30 secs and update all my data ? will it have access to the file that my app will then read ?

Comment: "and the WakefulIntentService will be able to "live" more than 30 secs and update all my data ?" The [`IntentService`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) will live as long as your `onHandleIntent()` (or `doWakefulWork()` in `WakefulIntentService`) is doing its work. "will it have access to the file that my app will then read ?" As much as your `BroadcastReceiver` does today, presumably. Note that I am not you, and therefore did not write your code, so I have no idea what this "file that my app will then read" is.

Comment: A last question if I may : How do I best access the app context (mContext => maybe "Context mContext = (Context) getApplicationContext();") within AppService.doWakefulWork ? The goal is to access my apps Preferences with "pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);" and my files with "FileOutputStream fOut = mContext.openFileOutput(Globals.mFileName, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);"

Comment: YES IT WORKS with Context mContext = (Context) getApplicationContext();

Comment: @CommonsWare : can u help me with this please : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187100/alarmmanager-working-well-in-emulator-but-not-in-real-device

Answer (score 1):

For information, I've tried with a new thread and it works when on Wifi (takes about 1'30" to update the data when phone is asleep, it doesn't get 'killed' !

```
//let's try with a new separate thread ?
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Refresh_HIST_DATA();
            }
          }).start();
```

but NOT when on Mobile (GPRS), as it gets killed after about 10 secs!

It's half-a-solution for the moment and I will try CommonsWare's solution for a cleaner/more sustainable approach...

Let's see if the new thread solution works allways fine or was just luck (I've tested only during a couple hours) ...

If anyone else has another suggestion, please do post it.

Comment: the new thread solution does not always work, so avoid ! Let's go for CommonsWare's solution then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thread. You can start a AsyncTask from your broadcast receiver onRecive() method. This will not block the UI thread. I myself have done same in my projects which is of same nature i.e. It has to post data every 1 hour.

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // start your Asynctask from here. which will post data in doInBackground() method
}
```