# Android notification keeps reappearing

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to get a better handle on notifications with the simple app shown below (at least the relevant parts). I would like to show a notification icon when the app is not destroyed, and remove the notification icon when it is destroyed; pretty simple right?

My problem is that when the fragment's onDestroyView event is fired the notification icon does disappear, but then reappears and I can't figure out why.

To try to figure things out a bit better I create a stop notification button that calls the `mServiceBinder`'s `stop()` method, which **does** remove the notification icon for good even though it is calling the same method called in the `onDestroyView` event.

Any ideas to what the problem is?

**MainActivityFragment**

```
package org.chrisolsen.notificationtest;

import ...

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ServiceConnection mServiceConn;
    private TestService.TestBinder mServiceBinder;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        Log.d("Fragment", "onDestroyView");

        // *try* to prevent services from restarting
        if (mServiceConn != null) {
            getActivity().unbindService(mServiceConn);
        }

        if (mServiceBinder != null) {
            mServiceBinder.stop();
        }

        mServiceConn = null;
        mServiceBinder = null;
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("Fragment", "onViewCreated");
        Button showButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        Button hideButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnHide);

        showButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("Fragment", "onCLick");

                mServiceConn = new ServiceConnection() {

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
                        Log.d("serviceConn", "onConnected");
                        mServiceBinder = (TestService.TestBinder) service;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
                        Log.d("serviceConn", "onDisconnected");
                    }
                };

                Intent service = new Intent(getActivity(), TestService.class);
                getActivity().startService(service);
                getActivity().bindService(service, mServiceConn, Context.BIND_ABOVE_CLIENT);
            }
        });

        hideButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mServiceBinder.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**TestService**

```
package org.chrisolsen.notificationtest;

import ...

public class TestService extends Service {

    public class TestBinder extends Binder {
        public void stop() {
            TestService.this.stopForeground(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("TestSErvice", "onDestroy");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new TestBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("TestSErvice", "onHandleIntent");
        Context c = getApplicationContext();

        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(c, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                c, 0, activityIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText("The Content Text")
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setContentTitle("The content title");

        startForeground(1, builder.build());

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The notification reappears because your service `onStartCommand` called after your activity closed. 
It is a bad place to create and show notification. `onStartCommand` method maybe called multiple times. Place the notification creation to the `onCreate` for example.

What do you mean when you wrote "app is not destroyed"? If you thought while your service is running, put the creation to the `onCreate` and remove it in `onDestroy`.

Comment: Moving the code within the `onStartCommand` results in the exact same issue. "app is not destroyed" means the onDestroy event is not fired. I don't understand what you mean in your last sentence, but there is nothing being created in the onDestroyView...

Comment: onStartCommand is only called multiple times only if you call startService multiple times. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182014/android-oncreate-or-onstartcommand-for-starting-service

Comment: try to use stopping service by `stopSelf()`

Answer (score 0):

Returning `START_STICKY` instead of `super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)`, is what I should've been doing.