# How to call Timer in a Service

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, countdowntimer

I have a `countdown timer`, that starts when user `Logged In`. After 10 Minutes it `Logged Out` User.

It works fine, but if user stops application, then timer stops working, and user is `logged in` forever.

So i put this whole thing in a service, so that it will work, either user stops application or not.

The problem is that, this has stopped working after adding `Countdown Timer` in `Service`. I have checked it on `debug mode`, and its not going into the `service`- `onCreate` method.

This is how i am calling the service.

```
 startService(new Intent(this,LogoutService.class));
```

My Service Class, calls the `CountdownTimer Class`, first this code was written in the place where i write `startService()` now

```
public class LogoutService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        UserLoggedInTimer logoutTimer= new UserLoggedInTimer(60000,1000);
        logoutTimer.setContext(getApplicationContext());
        logoutTimer.start();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

The countdown timer works perfectly fine when i call it without service, but here its just not getting into the service, i hope it will work fine, once my application starts the above service successfully.

Answer (score 1):

put it in `onStartCommand()` and make it return `START_STICKY`

refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14182014/android-oncreate-or-onstartcommand-for-starting-service)