# Service Timer Notification

Tags: android, service, timer, notifications

HI!

I want make service in OnCreate(), and every five minute, the service show notification..

can you show me about it??

thanks before :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver instead of Service - is that bad ? (Timeout problem) ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117350/alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-instead-of-service-is-that-bad-timeout-pr)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the TimerTask class with the postDelayed method.

```
private TimerTask mTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Whatever you want
          postDelayed(this, REPEAT_INTERVAL);   // rinse and repeat...
        }
    };
```

And in your OnCreate launching the TimerTask for first time:

```
postDelayed(mTask, INITIAL_DELAY);
```

You can find some information in this android article

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html