# Which class type should I use with AlarmManager?

Tags: java, android, alarm

I'm building an app which will work this way: enable Mobile Data or Wifi (WiFi if checkbox is checked) each X minutes for Y minute(s) then disable it.

What I've done:

- `MainActivity`: set an `AlarmManager` (with `setRepeating`) to execute
  `AlarmService` each X minutes.
- `AlarmService`: enable Mobile Data or Wifi
  then sets a new `AlarmManager` to call `DisableMD` in Y minute(s)
- `DisableMD`: disable Mobile Data or Wifi

`MainActivity` is an Activity and `AlarmService` and `DisableMD` are Services.

My questions:

1. Is a Service the best way in this case? Services run in background and I don't need it. I just need the `AlarmManager` to call a class which will perform an action once (turn on/off mobile data).
2. Will `AlarmManager` with setRepeating create a new Service everytime or only once?
3. I need the `AlarmService` to update a `TextView` in `MainActivity` with the time of last execution and the `AlarmService` to get the value of a checkbox (true or false) in the `MainActivity`. Implementing a Messenger is really confusing and thats one of the reasons I don't want a Service in this case.

So guys, could you answer my questions and/or tell me what to change in my app's "architecture"?
Thanks

Comment: There is rarely a *best* way of doing **anything** in programming, but rather a *fastest* or a *least painful* way. Find whats most appropriate for your scenario.

Comment: Your question asks what the "best way" to solve this is which probably leads many people to close this as "not constructive" as it makes the question subjective. However, I think that your question has a few points specific enough to warrant an answer. You might want to reword your question to avoid closure. I think there's a reasonable question in here.

Comment: I guess turn on/off the mobile data will be a a fast action anyway. I prefer a least painful way.

Comment: @kabuko I changed the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You *do* actually need to run code in the background it seems like (just not continuously). You're right though, a `Service` may not strictly be necessary. If your operation is very quick, you could potentially fit it into a [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117350/alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-instead-of-service-is-that-bad-timeout) other SO thread may also be of help. If your work takes any significant amount of time though, a `Service` is probably your best option.
2. Generally as you call the `Service` by intent, the same `Service` will be re-used if it's still alive from the last time. You'll want to read up on the [docs for `Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). The lifecycle information may be especially relevant here.
3. You don't actually need your `AlarmService` to interact with your `MainActivity`'s UI. It seems like what you want is for your `MainActivity` to set whether you're dealing with WiFi or mobile data, for it to display the last time of execution, for the `AlarmService` to set the last time of execution and for it to read whether you're dealing with WiFi or mobile data. Essentially you have two settings that you want to read and write from the `MainActivity` and `AlarmService`. Consider simply storing these in [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref). You can avoid the need to directly communicate between your `MainActivity` and `AlarmService` this way.

Comment: Your BroadcastReceiver will still run in the main thread, so either immediately offload to a background thread or use IntentService.