# AlarmManager in Android

Tags: android, android-alarms, android-broadcast

I have code which is to be run **daily**; for this I'm trying to use `AlarmManager`. This is my code for triggering alarms:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
}
```

This part of the code is calling `AlarmReciever` class as expected, but I want the code in the `AlarmReciever` class to be executed **only** once daily. It's being called multiple times. How do I restrict it?

This is the `AlarmReciever` class:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("in alarm reciever class");

    }
}
```

I'm trying to perform some business logic in the `onReceive()` method.

In the manifest.xml file:

```xml
<receiver android:name="com.xyz.reciever.AlarmReciever"></receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

are declared.

Comment: do you mean it is constantly alarming?

Comment: @kabuto178 yes its constantly alarming....I'm having a sysout in AlarmReciever class and its printing constantly...not once as expected..

Comment: Did you try using a calendar object as time reference?

Comment: @kabuto178 yeah...I tried Calendar object too. It's showing same result.

Comment: What is `AlarmReciever`?  What class does that extend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code you should be using to set your alarm would be this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, 0);      // <- HERE!!
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pi); // cancel any existing alarms
am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

since your `AlarmReciever` is a `BroadcastReceiver`.  Use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`.

If you have much work to do in your receiver's `onReceive()` method, you might also delegate it to an `IntentService`.  [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3117635/119114) if you decide to do that.

Comment: when `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is used, `AlarmReciever` class is not being called.

Comment: @AnilM, you will need to make sure the receiver is listed in the AndroidManifest.xml file.  For example, `<receiver android:name='your.mypackage.AlarmReceiver'></receiver>`. You can [see this for a more complete tutorial on using AlarmManager this way](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html)

Comment: @AnilM, also, make sure that the spelling in the manifest xml file matches the spelling in your code.  You actually spelled `AlarmReceiver` incorrectly (i <-> e) ... but the important thing is that the spellings match, of course.

Comment: @AnilM, then I think something **else** is going wrong, that you're not showing.  Using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` is the right way to alert your `BroadcastReceiver`.  Have you looked in your LogCat for any useful messages?